# It is possible to initialize a Span<T> field in a ref struct?

Tags: c#, memory, struct

This doesn't work because you can't directly initialize fields in structs:

```
public ref  struct WordCollection
    {     
        public Span<byte> words = stackalloc byte[100];
    }
```

The error is: 'WordCollection': cannot have instance property or field initializers in structs.

However, I also can't initialize it using the constructor:

```
public ref  struct WordCollection
    {     
        public Span<byte> words;

        public WordCollection(int size)
        {
            words = stackalloc byte[size];
        }
    }
```

The error here is: Field 'WordCollection.words' must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller.

This also doesn't work:

```
public ref  struct WordCollection
    {     
        public Span<byte> words;
    }

public class Test
    {
       public static void WordProc()
        {
            WordCollection wordCollection = new WordCollection();
            wordCollection.words = stackalloc byte[100];
        } 
    }
```

The error is: A result of a stackalloc expression of type 'Span' cannot be used in this context because it may be exposed outside of the containing method.

So, the question is: it is possible to initialize a `Span<T>` field of a ref struct?

Comment: The error I see for your middle piece of code is entirely different to the one you're quoting here.

Comment: `because it may be exposed outside of the containing method.` is literally telling you the problem: you cannot `stackalloc` anywhere in the construction of the struct because it's going to disappear as soon as you return to the caller (it's a *stack allocation* after all) @JonSkeet is right in his answer that you *have to* pass the `Span` in from the caller method.

Comment: Interestingly, the compiler *will* allow `new WordCollection { words = stackalloc byte[100] }`, which seems inconsistent. At least, there's nothing in the definition of object initializers that would explain why that would be allowed when a separate assignment would not be.

Answer (score 3):

This may well not be the nicest approach, but you can pass a `Span<byte>` into the constructor:

```cs
public ref struct WordCollection
{
    public Span<byte> words;

    public WordCollection(Span<byte> words)
    {
        this.words = words;
    }
}
```

Then:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        WordCollection words = new WordCollection(stackalloc byte[100]);
    }
}
```

It really depends on what you're trying to do with it though...

Comment: Just thinking: why does case #3 not work? It's declared as `ref struct` so compiler knows it's not going to escape

Comment: @Charlieface: I'm afraid the subtleties of this one are beyond me. I've always found the `ref struct` parts fairly hard to understand :(

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this works:

```
public ref  struct WordCollection
    {     
        public Span<byte> words;
    }

public class Test
    {
       public static void WordProc()
        {
            WordCollection wordCollection = new WordCollection {
                wordCollection.words = stackalloc byte[100]
            };
        } 
    }
```

It's a bit weird and not the way I'd prefer but gets the job done.

Comment: This doesn't compile; `wordCollection.words` is not legal to use in an initializer. Just `words` is.